# How to click on an option in li tag

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am trying to do following :

Go to yelp.com
Select “Restaurants” after clcking in the drop-down box in Find

I am not able to click on "Restaurants" as xpath is not able to locate element.

Comment: Please share your code and html

Comment: What issue have you encountered? Do you have a question? Be specific.

Answer (score 0):

I checked with selenium-webdriver, junit. Below code is working fine for me. Check this resolves for you.

```
  @Before
  public void setUp() throws Exception {
    driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    baseUrl = "http://www.yelp.com/";
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  }

  @Test
  public void testYelpRest() throws Exception {
    driver.get(baseUrl + "");
    driver.findElement(By.id("find_desc")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.id("find_desc")).sendKeys("Restaurants");
    driver.findElement(By.id("find_desc")).sendKeys(Keys.DOWN);
    driver.findElement(By.id("find_desc")).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
    for (int second = 0;; second++) {
        if (second >= 60) fail("timeout");
        try { if (isElementPresent(By.xpath("//span[@class='pagination-results-window']"))) break; } catch (Exception e) {}
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }
  }

  @After
  public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    driver.quit();
    String verificationErrorString = verificationErrors.toString();
    if (!"".equals(verificationErrorString)) {
      fail(verificationErrorString);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try below code, i m sure it will work..:)

```
 public class Yelp_dropdown {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();

        driver.get("http://www.yelp.com/");

        WebDriverWait w= new WebDriverWait(driver,5);

        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='find_desc']")).click();

        w.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath(".//*[@class='suggestion-detail suggestion-name' and contains (text(), 'Restaurants')]"))).click();
```